# Air for Mobile - IP Address

Tags: android, ios, flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking to score a LOCAL IP ADDRESS for a a mobile device (both Android and iOS). I know that you can get an IP via PHP but I need the local IP. And yes, I know that you can get it from a PHP call on a local machine running a server, but this isn't going to be the case for a regular user. I have accessed the "NetworkInfo" and tapped into the ".findInterfaces();" section of the class, however, mobile devices that "isSupported" returns TRUE don't have access to the interfaces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer, I'm afraid. NetworkInfo should work on Android if you specify the correct permissions: ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

Unfortunately, the NetworkInfo class isn't implemented on iOS, so I don't have an answer for that part. (Another job for native extensions in AIR 3?)

Comment: Sadly as of now all the ways that you could normally access the network status and info still ins't accessible in AIR for Mobile.